# when i place order successfully and try to shop again by adding product to cart it show asked to login again

Tags: magento2

When i place order successfully and try to shop again by adding product to cart it show asked to login again in magento2.2.4.
It was happen in Api.

Comment: Do you face this each time you do it?

Comment: yes every time when login.